# Is it possible to customize invisible's characters in xcode4?

Tags: xcode4, special-characters

I'm using xcode 4 and I would like to see special characters (spaces, tabs, etc.) all time. I could toggle showing them by "Editor"->"Show Invisibles".

But the way how it's showing in xcode doesn't satisfy me:
[image]

Is it possible to customize this characters?

Thanks.

Comment: Maaaaybe... but its probably hidden deep deep within a binary somewhere.

Comment: At least they didn't choose the  for the whitespace character.

Comment: Yeah it's annoying. I tried changing the color for "invisibles" to very transparent but XCode seems to ignore that - sigh.

Comment: @w00t: You made this comment about ignoring transparency in 2012; it's 2017 and the same problem exists.

Answer (score -1):

i do it by customize the key binding 
set a key shortcut for the show invisible character in the xcode->preferences->key binding enter invisibles in search box "invisibles" option  'show invisible' appear set a shortcut for it of your choice then use it for on/off the show invisible characters 
http://i1144.photobucket.com/albums/o483/saqibzaidi/ABC.jpg