# Xcode turn off underscore (editor)

Tags: xcode, editor

How can I turn off the underscore in Xcode?
Each space is an underscore. (see screenshot)

Screenschot:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595759/is-it-possible-to-customize-invisibles-characters-in-xcode4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go `Editor -> Hide Invisibles`

[image]